# Kernel of irreducible representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory

I'm try to prove that if we have  G an finite group and ρ1,ρ2,⋯,ρm be pairwisely non-isomorphic irreducible representations of G wich the field is the complex number so ⋂kerρi=1 ( ⋂i-->1 to m)
I stared the proof by extending a representation ρ:G→GLn(C) linearly, we get a representation  L:CG→Mn(C). Since elements of G form a basis for CG, I'm thinking about using Maschke’s Theorem that the algebra CG is semisimple in the sense of Wedderburn. By the
classical Wedderburn-Artin Theorem, CG ∼= Mn1
(C) ⊕ · · · ⊕ Mnm
(C).
but I dont know how I can finish the proof, I'll be happy if someone helped me finish the details, or have another proof more simple

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Artin-Wedderburn.

If $g\in G$ is in the kernel of all irreducible representations, then it acts trivially on all irreducible representations. Since all representations are direct sums of irreps, this means $g$ must act trivially on all representations. In particular, it must act trivially on the regular rep $\mathbb{C}G$. But multiplying $e$ by $g$ gives $g$ within the regular rep, the only way this is trivial is if $g=e$.

You can also do this argument by consider the kernels of the algebra homomorphisms $\mathbb{C}[G]\to\mathrm{End}(V)$s instead of merely the group homomorphisms $G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$. You can do this to show the algebra homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[G]\to\bigoplus\mathrm{End}(V)$ is one-to-one. By determining the multiplicity of irreps in the regular rep, you can also show this is onto (or using Jacobson density theorem), and thus *prove* Artin-Wedderburn.

Comment: Can you please explain this- multiplying e by g gives g within the regular rep. and how its look in equation. @runway44

Comment: $\rho_{\Bbb CG}(g)e=g$.

Comment: Thank you ! @runway44